# onChange event with rails3 javascript jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, onchange

I have a voting form where you can also add another answer, and then when you do that only then the voting button should appear...

EDIT 2!!!

In my views/index.html.erb i have:

```
<table>
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<% for answer in question.answers %>


            <td>Other:</td>
            <td>        
              <%= form_tag('/vote/new_answer', :method => "post") do %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag('answer[question_id]', question.id) %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag('answer[user_id]', current_user.id) %>
            <div class="other_answer">
              <%= text_field_tag('answer[content]') %>
            </div>
          </td>
            <td>
                <div class="other_answer_button", hidden='true'>
              <%= submit_tag('Vote') %>
                </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

On my application.js file i have:

```
$(function() {
    $(".other_answer input").change(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
            $(".other_answer_button").hide();
        }
        else {
            $(".other_answer_button").show();
       }       
    });
});
```

Still the same remains:

Now it works... but if i put some text in one of the text fields all the vote buttons appear. And it only should show the one vote button at that specific answer.

Should i add somehow an incremental id to every text input field and also to the vote buttons?

Anyone?
Regards,
Thijs

Comment: In your js, change `onChange(function)` to `change(function)`. http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Nope, doesn't do anything... thanks anyway!

Comment: You have hidden the submit button but you are modifying the div which contains it (and it has no hidden attr).

Comment: Now you are breaking the laws of html, attribute id is to uniquely identify the element and there shouldn't be elements with same id!, so  first thing is change id to class, will update the answer assuming you changed id to class, but solution is very markup dependent.

Comment: Do you mean because it's an array, (a table) that there are more than one elements with the same id... so instead of <div id="other_answer"> it should be <div class="other_answer"> etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are few other things as well which needs to be revised in your js code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".other_answer input").change(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
            $("input", $(this).parents("td").next()).hide();
        }
        else {
            $("input", $(this).parents("td").next()).hide();
       }       
    });
});
```

The solution is very markup dependent and selector might not work as it is as I hove not tested, so try to play around with it a little, if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, but still it doesn't work... couldn't there be something wrong in the way the textfield is called <div id="other_answer"> should be right? And is: if ($.trim($("#other_answer").val()) == "") correct, because now it is true if the field is empty, and it only should show the button if the field has at least one character.

Comment: Yes!! It's almost perfect... (i've also switched the show and hide) but now it only shows the "Vote" button when i leave the input field (after i typed something) i have to click on something other than the input field... So how to make it when it updates during the typing??

Comment: I also put input after the $("#other_answer_button input") like that. Only now - i have an array of questions - all the vote buttons appear when i type in the tet field and go outside the field and click again... see the editted question

Comment: It works perfectly!! $(this).parents("td").next() did the trick!! Now i need to figure out how i can check this after every keypress...

Comment: $(".other_answer input").keyup(function()